# Angular 4 Application Home Page not Showing Login screen

Tags: javascript, angular, http, authentication

For one of the Angular 4 application that I'm working on, I have the following app.component.html:

```
<app-layout-header></app-layout-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-layout-footer></app-layout-footer>
```

This is my app.routing.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The app.module.ts is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {
  ApiService,
  AuthGuard,
  FooterComponent,
  HeaderComponent,
  JwtService,
  ProfilesService,
  SharedModule,
  UserService
} from './shared';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    AuthGuard,
    JwtService,
    ProfilesService,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want this bit of html (this is actually my login.component.html) to be displayed when the user access the application at http://localhost:4200/

```
<div class="auth-page">
  <div class="container page">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But strangely when I access the url http://localhost:4200, I see the following screen:

[image]

So there are two problems:

1. Why is the URL http://localhost:4200/#/ instead of http://localhost:4200/
2. What is wrong with what I'm doing so that I can get the Login html getting displayed?

Please help!

Comment: There is no routes mentioned . why the routing declaration `RouterModule.forRoot([], { useHash: true })` has empty array? It should be array of `route definitions`

Comment: I edited my post with the RouterModule! But still not enough! Would you take a look now?

Comment: there is only one line `const rootRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([], { useHash: true });` . But the major is, how we defining the `route paths`

Comment: I have added the app.routing.ts which is where I have defined the route paths! Is that what you mean?

Comment: 1. You have usehash set to true... 2. Take a look at your AuthGuard. Do you have it route to the logincomponent?

Comment: Ah yes..and also there seems two `Root router modules` are imported as `RouterModule.forRoot()` can you use only one as `.forRoot` and others as `.forChild`

Comment: I have removed the empty forRoot and I now have only one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `#` is added properly due to your router configuration (`useHash: true`):

```
const rootRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([], { useHash: true });
```

2) To show `LoginComponent` you have to:

- use `redirectTo` property of default path
- or manually call `routerService.navigateByUrl("/login")` call from `AppComponent` or `HomeComponent` or `AuthGuard`